# Extended Euclidean Algorithm to find modular multiplicative inverse of polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}_m[X]/P(X)$ if m is not prime?

Tags: polynomials, modular-arithmetic, inverse, integers, euclidean-algorithm

I'm looking into modular polynomial rings over the integers (if that's the right term?) i.e. $\mathbb{Z}_m[X]/P(X)$ where $\mathbb{Z}_m$ is the ring of integers modulo m, and P(X) is some polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}_m$. Note that m is not necessarily prime so $\mathbb{Z}_m[X]$ may not be a field.

I wish to understand how to calculate the multiplicative inverse of polynomials (or should I call it polynomial classes) in such rings. I think I understand how to use the Extended Euclidean Algorithm, which works fine if m is prime. But if m is not prime I run astray.

For example: say R=$\mathbb{Z}_4[X]/(X^3-1)$ and find the inverse of $2x+1$ in R.
I know that the solution is $2x+1$, since $(2x+1)^2=1$ in R.
But right in the first step I need to multiply $2x+1$ with something and subtract that from $x^3-1$ to reduce its degree. But this is impossible since 2 is invertible (mod 4).

Another example: same R=$\mathbb{Z}_4[X]/(X^3-1)$ and find the inverse of $3x^2+2x+2$ in R.
I know that the solution is $2x^2+3x+2$, since $(3x^2+2x+2)\cdot(2x^2+3x+2)=1$ in R.
In the first step I multiply $3x^2+2x+2$ by $3x$ and subtract that from $x^3-1$ which leaves $2x2+2x+3$. And now I run into the same problem.

Am I doing it wrong, or is there a better way to either find an inverse in such cases or find that it doesn't exist?

Comment: There's an algorithm similar to Buchberger's algorithm to calculate a nice generating set of an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$.  So in your example, applying that to the ideal $\langle 4, 2X+1, X^3-1 \rangle$ gives that it's the unit ideal, and tracking the linear combination which gives 1 will tell you the multiplicative inverse.  If you don't get that it's a unit ideal, then the polynomial doesn't have a multiplicative inverse.

Comment: @DanielSchepler thanks, would you happen to know an explanation or example of that somewhere online? I'm not familiar with Buchberger's algorithm, looked it up but I'm not familiar Gröbner bases either, and couldn't really figure out the relationship to inverting polynomials myself.

Answer (score 1):

Given $f\in \Bbb{Z}[x]/(p^2,U)$ using the extended euclidean algorithm find some $g$ (if it exists, otherwise $f$ is not a unit) such that $fg=1\in \Bbb{Z}[x]/(p,U)$

So there is some $r$ such that $fg=1+pr$ in $\Bbb{Z}[x]/(p^2,U)$.

The inverse of $f\in \Bbb{Z}[x]/(p^2,U)$ is of the form $g+ph$.

Since $f(g+ph) = 1+p r+fph$, we want $fph=-pr$ in $\Bbb{Z}[x]/(p^2,U)$ ie. $fh =-r$ in $\Bbb{Z}[x]/(p,U)$,

ie. $h = -rg$ in $\Bbb{Z}[x]/(p,U)$ and the inverse of $f$ in $\Bbb{Z}[x]/(p^2,U)$ is $$g-prg$$

It works the same way, repeating the same idea $n$ times, for finding the inverse of $f\in \Bbb{Z}[x]/(p^n,U)$.

For the inverse of $f\in \Bbb{Z}[x]/(m,U)$ factorize $m$ in prime powers, solve for the inverse modulo each prime power, then mix the inverses using the isomorphism  $\Bbb{Z}[x]/(m,U)\to \prod_j \Bbb{Z}[x]/(p_j^{n_j},U)$.

Comment: Thanks, I try to follow but don't understand everything. I'm not familiar with the $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(p^2,U)$ notation, exactly what do you mean by $p^2$ and U here? Is there an example of this approach somewhere online? And as for factorizing m in prime powers and solving for the inverse modulo each prime, if I take 2x+1 modulo 2 I get 1, I don't see how that leads me back to the 2x+1 inverse?

Answer (score 1):

There is a version of Buchberger's algorithm to find Groebner bases of ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.  (Where in this case, the "initial term" of a polynomial includes the coefficient, as opposed to the case of Buchberger's algorithm for polynomials over a field.)  For the special case of a single variable over $\mathbb{Z}$, the algorithm can be stated as follows: keep a list of generators sorted by increasing degree, and then by increasing absolute value of coefficient of the initial term.  At each step, multiply one of the elements by $x$ raised to the difference between that generator's degree and the degree of the next element in the list.  Then, repeatedly subtract powers of $x$ times previous elements to reduce to the smallest initial term possible.  If at the end, you still have a nonzero polynomial, then add it to the generating set.  An alternate move, if you have any element whose leading term has a larger initial coefficient than any previous term, is to do the reduction modulo previous terms as above; if you end up with zero, you can remove the element, and otherwise you can replace the element with the remainder.  Once you have a situation where none of these moves changes the list, you have a Groebner basis.

For an example, let us use this to find an inverse of $3x^2 + 2x + 2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_4[x] / \langle x^3 - 1 \rangle$.  In order to do this, we will apply the above procedure to find a Groebner basis of the ideal $I = \langle 4, 3x^2+2x+2, x^3-1 \rangle$ of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.  We will furthermore track exactly how each element is a combination of $p_1=4, p_2=3x^2+2x+2, p_3=x^3-1$.  Thus, we start with
$$I = \langle 4 = p_1, 3x^2+2x+2 = p_2, x^3 - 1 = p_3 \rangle.$$
First, let us try multiplying the generator $4$ by $x^2$ to match the degree of the next generator in the list, getting $4x^2 = x^2 p_1$.  Then, subtract $3x^2+2x+2$ to give
$$(4x^2) - (3x^2+2x+2) = x^2-2x-2 = x^2 p_1 - p_2.$$
At this point, we cannot reduce the leading term any more, so we add this to the basis:
$$I = \langle 4=p_1, x^2-2x-2=x^2 p_1-p_2, 3x^2+2x+2=p_2, x^3-1=p_3 \rangle.$$
The next move we will make will be to reduce the third element modulo the previous ones: if we take $3x^2+2x+2$ and subtract 3 times $x^2-2x-2$, we get:
$$(3x^2+2x+2) - 3(x^2-2x-2) = 8x+8 = -3x^2p_1 + 4p_2.$$
Now, if we subtract $2x$ times the generator $4$, we get $8$, and again subtracting $2$ times the generator $4$, we get 0.  Therefore, we can remove the third element from the basis to get:
$$I = \langle 4=p_1, x^2-2x-2=x^2 p_1-p_2, x^3-1=p_3 \rangle.$$
Next, we will reduce $x^3-1$ modulo the previous elements.  First, subtract $x$ times $x^2-2x-2$:
$$(x^3-1) - x(x^2-2x-2) = 2x^2+2x-1 = -x^3p_1 + xp_2 + p_3.$$
Next, subtract 2 times $x^2-2x-2$:
$$(2x^2+2x-1) - 2(x^2-2x-2) = 6x+3 = (-x^3-2x^2)p_1 + (x+2)p_2 + p_3.$$
Finally, subtract $x$ times the generator $4$:
$$(6x+3) - x(4) = 2x+3 = (-x^3-2x^2-x)p_1 + (x+2)p_2 + p_3.$$
At this point, we cannot reduce the leading term any more, so we can replace; and after doing this replacement and resorting the list, we get:
$$I = \langle 4=p_1, 2x+3=(-x^3-2x^2-x)p_1+(x+2)p_2+p_3, x^2-2x-2=x^2p_1-p_2 \rangle.$$
From here, if you multiply the generator $4$ by $x$ and then reduce modulo $2x+3$ and then modulo $4$, you get $-2 = (2x^3+4x^2+3x+1)p_1 + (-2x-4)p_2 + (-2)p_3$.  Before adding to the ideal, you might as well negate, and you get:
$$I = \langle 2=(-2x^3-4x^2-3x-1)p_1 + (2x+4)p_2 + 2p_3,\\4=p_1,\\2x+3=(-x^3-2x^2-x)p_1+(x+2)p_2+p_3,\\
x^2-2x-2=x^2p_1-p_2 \rangle.$$
You can now remove $4$ from the list since it is a multiple of $2$.  Finally, if you reduce $2x+3$ modulo $2$, you get
$$1 = (2x^4+5x^3+5x^2+3x+1)p_1 + (-2x^2-5x-2)p_2 + (-2x-1)p_3.$$
However, since $p_1$ and $p_3$ are both equivalent to 0 in $\mathbb{Z}_4[x] / \langle x^3 - 1 \rangle$, we conclude that $-2x^2-5x-2$ is the multiplicative inverse of $p_2 = 3x^2+2x+2$.

(If we had reached a point where no further moves would change the list, and neither 1 nor -1 was in the list, then this would have shown that the selected polynomial would not have been a unit in the quotient ring by the other polynomials.)

---

For information, here is a transcript of the input to Sagemath that I used to track the coefficients:

```
R.<x> = ZZ[]
M = R^4
p1 = R(4)
p2 = 3*x^2+2*x+2
p3 = x^3-1
B=[M((p1,1,0,0)),M((p2,0,1,0)),M((p3,0,0,1))]
B
x^2*B[0]-B[1]
B2=[B[0],_,*B[1:]]
B2
B2[2]-3*B2[1]
_-2*x*B2[0]
_-2*B2[0]
B3=[*B2[:2],*B2[3:]]
B3
B3[2]-x*B3[1]
_-2*B3[1]
_-x*B3[0]
B4=[*B3[:2],_]
B4
B5=[B4[0],B4[2],B4[1]]
B5
x*B5[0]-2*B5[1]
_+B5[0]
B6=[-_,*B5[1:]]
B6[1]-x*B6[0]
_-B6[0]
(2*x^4+5*x^3+5*x^2+3*x+1)*p1+(-2*x^2-5*x-2)*p2+(-2*x-1)*p3
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear and detailed reply, very much appreciated! Looks promising, I'm diving into this in detail to fully understand everything and comment further if I have any questions. Thanks so much again!  